# How do I display text inline with an image?

Tags: css, html

I have an image which is on the right and the text needs to be beside it on the left with the start of the text inline with the top of the image, how would I do this?

```css
#pic0 {
 width:100%;
}
#pic0img {
 display: inline-block;
 height: auto;
 margin-left:50%;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
pic0txt {
 margin-right:52%;
 width:48%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pic0">
     <div id="pic0img">
        <img src="Images/Activities/pic0.fw.png" width="50%"
         onmouseover="this.src='Images/Activities/pic0.fw.png'"
   onmouseout="this.src='Images/Activities/pic0.fw.png'"          />
        </div>
        <div id="pic0txt">
         <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this simplified snippet (remove `border`s which are just for test):

```css
#pic0txt {
  display: inline-block; border:1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:48%;
}

#pic0img {
  display: inline-block; border:1px solid red; 
  width:48%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="pic0txt">test</div>
  <img id="pic0img" src="https://www-asp.azureedge.net/v-2016-11-01-012/images/ui/home-free-courses.png" />
</div>

<hr/>

<div>
  <img id="pic0img" src="https://www-asp.azureedge.net/v-2016-11-01-012/images/ui/home-free-courses.png" />
  <div id="pic0txt">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: partly like i want it, except the text needs to be inline with the top of the image, sorry if the question wasn't clear enough

Comment: any way i could have the image on the left and text on the right? tried to edit it and do it myself but didnt work

Comment: updated to show inverse text and image order, if its not what you mean, just give feedback

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` on the parent, then `flex-grow` on each flex item so they'll be 50% width, and set the image to `width: 100%` so it fills it's parent.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: broke most of the other content on the page, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple and easy trick:

```
<div id="pic0">
    <div id="pic0img">


        <p> <img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31300000/beautiful-heart-pic-beautiful-pictures-31395948-333-500.jpg" width="50%"
        onmouseover="this.src='Images/Activities/pic0.fw.png'"
        onmouseout="this.src='Images/Activities/pic0.fw.png'" />test</p>

    </div>

</div>

#pic0 {
    width:20%;
}
#pic0img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left:50%;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: wait i will fix it

Comment: the image isnt on the right and the text is stuck at the bottom of the image, partly what im looking for though